# Button in Ajax tabContainer is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using ajax tabContainer with update panel but all of my buttons are not working as if they have no code written behind. Not even error massages, nothing!

My tabContainer setting: autoPostBack=false, not using ActiveTabChanged thing, I just want to use this container as a host of my 3 tabs which has 1 or 2 buttons in each tab.

When I tried to update information in Tab2, all the RequiredFielsValidator activates in Tab1 so I tried validation group thing but doesn't work. Tab1 is still grouped as validationGroup='first'

Source code

```
<ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager>
     <ajaxToolKit:TabContainer ID="TabContainerUser" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" >
         <ajaxToolKit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Register" ID="TabPanel1" TabIndex="0">
             <HeaderTemplate>
                    Register
                </HeaderTemplate>
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="btnReg" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnReg_Click" ValidationGroup="first" />
</ContentTemplate>
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </ContentTemplate>
         </ajaxToolKit:TabPanel>
```

My design:Displays user data and if I click Edit
[image: Displays user data and if I click Edit]

After clicking edit, my Tab1 goes like this 
[image: After clicking edit, my Tab1 goes like this]

Comment: What validation groups are your RequiredFieldsValidators attached to?

Comment: Ooops! good point! actually none... I'll try now and get back to you soon! so set RequiredFieldsValidators to 'first' right?

Comment: Yeah, if you set them on the 'first' validation group then they should only fire on the btnReg_Click event.

Comment: Just tried but still the Register button doesn't work.....

Comment: As in the event is not firing?

Comment: Sorry, my internet went down for a while. Yes, the event is not firing but I think my C# code is right coz I used almost the same code in the previous project, as a matter of fact, this project is very similar to what I did previously but this time doesn't work and I don't know why......

Comment: If I click Register, it wouldn't load or show any error messages, it's like I didn't write any code behind....

Comment: If you cannot use autoPostBack=true, then you may need to use onClientClick to use script to call your event. This is because you are not posting back to the server click event, thus you are not able to use the server method.